# Let $f: Z_{12} \to Z_{12}$ be defined by $f(x)=5x+8$. Prove that $f$ is injective and surjective but not an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I already know how to prove this is an injection, but showing the function is onto is proving to be tricky. I think. If I want to show that for all $b$ in $Z_{12}$ there exists an $a$ in $Z_{12}$ such that $f(a)=b$. Wouldnt I want to say that $a=(b-8)/5$ is in $Z_{12}$? But it's not true unless that is under mod $12$. I need a little bit of help please.

Comment: An injective function from a set of size $12$ to another set of size $12$ *has* to be surjective.  And yes, $f(x)$ should be calculated mod $12$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z_{12}$ isn't a subset of $\Bbb Z$. So for $8,9\in\Bbb Z_{12}$, we have $8+9=5$. Always. Every time. There is no "not modulo 12".

Comment: It may be that your difficulties stem from not understanding what $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$. Its elements are residue *classes*,  not just integers from $0$ to $11$. They are just an often used collection of *representatives* of those residue classes. This is the reason why those elements are often listed as $\overline{0}$, $\overline{1}$, $\ldots$, $\overline{11}$. You are only *allowed* to drop those bars when you can automatically infer the meaning from the context. This comes quickly enough, but does take a few months. May be you are not there, yet? Keep working on it, and all becomes clear.

Answer (score 2):

If $\bar x,\bar y\in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with $f(\bar x)=f(\bar y)$, then $5\bar x+\bar 8 = 5\bar y + \bar 8$, from which it is immediate that $\bar x=\bar y$ (division by $5$ is permissible as $5$ and $12$ are coprime). Now let $\bar z\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Then because $5$ and $12$ are coprime, there exists $\bar w\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ such that $\bar z = \bar 5\bar w$. It follows then that $f(\bar w-\bar 8)=\bar z$.

To see that $f$ is not a homomorphism, consider that $f(\bar 0) = \bar 5\bar 0 + \bar 8=\bar8\ne\bar 0$, so $f$ does not map the identity to the identity.

As a side note, we are considering multiplication as well as addition in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. So shouldn't this be a question of rings and not a question of groups?

Answer (score 0):

You said you already have injectivity.

The comments provide two ways to prove surjectivity. Either argue that an injective map from a set of 12 elements to a set of 12 elements has to be surjective or compute explicitely in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ to show it directly.

The final part aks to prove that it is not an isomorphism. The trick here is that if one writes $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ one usually thinks of it as a group not just a set. Your map $f$ is an isomorphism of sets (it has to be because the sets are finite and it is injective and surjective) but it is not an isomorphism of groups. An isomorphism of groups needs to preserve the group structure as well. This implies that the identity element is mapped to the identity, this is not the case here.